# 2D Character falls off the map in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, unity3d-2dtools

I am currently working on a project for one of the courses i am taking.
I am making a 2D game in unity3D, and i have a small problem, every time i run the game my character keeps on falling through the map, even though i have added a rigidbody2D and a boxCollider2D to both my character and the foreground. The code is attached, it is in C# and it is a bit long. Thank you so much in advance ..

```
enter code here 
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterController2D : MonoBehaviour 
{
private const float SkinWidth = .02f;
private const int TotalHorizontalRays = 8;
private const int TotalVerticalRays = 4;

private static readonly float SlopeLimitTanget = Mathf.Tan (75f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);

public LayerMask PlatformMask;
public ControllerParameters2D DefaultParameters;


public ControllerState2D State { get; private set; }
public Vector2 Velocity { get { return _velocity; }}
public bool HandleCollisions { get; set; }
//Return overrideparamteres if it is not null, if it is null it will return DefaultParameters
public ControllerParameters2D Parameters { get { return _overrideParameters ?? DefaultParameters; } }
public GameObject StandingOn { get; private set;}
public Vector3 PlatformVelocity { get; private set;}

public bool CanJump 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if(Parameters.JumpRestrictions == ControllerParameters2D.JumpBehavior.CanJumpAnywhere)
                return _jumpIn <= 0;

            if(Parameters.JumpRestrictions == ControllerParameters2D.JumpBehavior.CanJumpOnGround)
                return State.IsGrounded;

            return false;
        }
    }


private Vector2 _velocity;
private Transform _transform;
private Vector3 _localScale;
private BoxCollider2D _boxCollider;
private ControllerParameters2D _overrideParameters;
private float _jumpIn;
private GameObject _lastStandingOn;
private Vector3
        _activeGlobalPlatformPoint,
        _activeLocalPlatformPoint;

private Vector3
        _raycastTopLeft,
        _raycastBottomRight,
        _raycastBottomLeft;

private float _verticalDistanceBetweenRays,
_horizonatalDistanceBetweenRays;

public void Awake()
{
    HandleCollisions = true;
    State = new ControllerState2D();
    _transform = transform;
    _localScale = transform.localScale;
    _boxCollider = GetComponent <BoxCollider2D>();

    // Absolute Value
    var colliderWidth = _boxCollider.size.x * Mathf.Abs(transform.localScale.x) - (2 * SkinWidth);
    _horizonatalDistanceBetweenRays = colliderWidth / (TotalVerticalRays - 1);

    var colliderHeight = _boxCollider.size.y * Mathf.Abs( transform.localScale.y ) - (2 * SkinWidth);
    _verticalDistanceBetweenRays = colliderHeight / (TotalHorizontalRays - 1);
}

public void AddForce(Vector2 force)
{
    _velocity = force;
}

public void SetForce(Vector2 force)
{
    _velocity += force;
}

public void SetHorizontalForce(float x)
{
    _velocity.x = x;
}

public void SetVerticalForce(float y)
{
    _velocity.y = y;
}

public void Jump()
{
    AddForce(new Vector2(0, Parameters.JumpMagnitude));
    _jumpIn = Parameters.JumpFrequency;
}

public void LateUpdate()
{
    _jumpIn -= Time.deltaTime;
    //We force the player to go up or down based on the gravity
    _velocity.y += Parameters.Gravity * Time.deltaTime; 
    //Move the characther per his velocity scaled by time
    Move (Velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

// Ensures the player doesn't fall off the map or move through the wall
private void Move(Vector2 deltaMovement)
{
    var wasGrounded = State.IsCollidingBelow;
    State.Reset();

    if(HandleCollisions)
    {
        HandlePlatforms();
        CalculateRayOrigins();

        if(deltaMovement.y < 0 && wasGrounded)
            HandleVerticalSlope(ref deltaMovement);

        if(Mathf.Abs(deltaMovement.x) > .001f)
            MoveHorizontally(ref deltaMovement);

        MoveVertically(ref deltaMovement);

        CorrectHorizontalPlacement(ref deltaMovement, true);
        CorrectHorizontalPlacement(ref deltaMovement, false);
    }

    _transform.Translate(deltaMovement, Space.World);

    if (Time.deltaTime > 0)
        _velocity = deltaMovement / Time.deltaTime;

    _velocity.x = Mathf.Min (_velocity.x, Parameters.MaxVelocity.x);
    _velocity.y = Mathf.Min (_velocity.y, Parameters.MaxVelocity.y);

    if(State.IsMovingUpSlope)
        _velocity.y = 0;

    //Standing on the platform  
    if(StandingOn != null)
    {
            _activeGlobalPlatformPoint = transform.position;
            _activeLocalPlatformPoint = StandingOn.transform.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position);

            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, _activeGlobalPlatformPoint);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, _activeLocalPlatformPoint + StandingOn.transform.position);

            if(_lastStandingOn != StandingOn)
            {
                //If the last thing we are standing on is not null, send a message to leave it
                if(_lastStandingOn != null)
                    _lastStandingOn.SendMessage("ControllerExist2D", this, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);

                //Inform what we are standing on that we have entered
                StandingOn.SendMessage("ControllerEnter2D", this, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                _lastStandingOn = StandingOn;
            }

            //Invoke the platform that we are standing on it
            else if (StandingOn != null)
                StandingOn.SendMessage("ControllerStay2D", this, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver); 
    }
    else if (_lastStandingOn != null)
    {
        _lastStandingOn.SendMessage("ControllerExit2D", this, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        _lastStandingOn = null;
    }
}

private void HandlePlatforms()
{
        //Calculate the velocity of the platform
        if(StandingOn != null)
        {
            var newGlobalPlatformPoint = StandingOn.transform.TransformPoint(_activeLocalPlatformPoint);
            var moveDistance = newGlobalPlatformPoint - _activeGlobalPlatformPoint;
            //Sticks the player on the platform, wherever the platform teleport the players stays on it
            if(moveDistance != Vector3.zero)
                transform.Translate(moveDistance, Space.World);

            PlatformVelocity = (newGlobalPlatformPoint - _activeGlobalPlatformPoint) / Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
            PlatformVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        StandingOn = null;
}

private void CorrectHorizontalPlacement(ref Vector2 deltaMovement, bool isRight)
{
        var halfwidth = (_boxCollider.size.x * _localScale.x) / 2f;
        var rayOrigin = isRight ? _raycastBottomRight : _raycastBottomLeft;

        if(isRight)
            rayOrigin.x -= (halfwidth - SkinWidth);
        else
            rayOrigin.x += (halfwidth - SkinWidth);

        var rayDirection = isRight ? Vector2.right : -Vector2.right;
        var offset = 0f;

        for(var i = 1; i <= TotalHorizontalRays - 1; i++)
        {
            var rayVector = new Vector2(deltaMovement.x + rayOrigin.x, deltaMovement.y + rayOrigin.y + (i * _verticalDistanceBetweenRays));
            Debug.DrawRay(rayVector, rayDirection * halfwidth, isRight ? Color.cyan : Color.magenta);

            var raycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayVector, rayDirection, halfwidth, PlatformMask);
            if(!raycastHit)
                continue;


            offset = isRight ? ((raycastHit.point.x - _transform.position.x) - halfwidth) : (halfwidth - (_transform.position.x - raycastHit.point.x));
        }

        deltaMovement.x += offset;
}

private void CalculateRayOrigins()
{
        var size = new Vector2 (_boxCollider.size.x * Mathf.Abs (_localScale.x), _boxCollider.size.y * Mathf.Abs (_localScale.y)) / 2;
        var center = new Vector2(_boxCollider.center.x * _localScale.x, _boxCollider.center.y * _localScale.y);

        //Location of the player, then we add the box collider to it relative to the center of the player
        _raycastTopLeft = _transform.position + new Vector3 (center.x - size.x + SkinWidth, center.y + size.y - SkinWidth);
        _raycastBottomRight = _transform.position + new Vector3 (center.x + size.x - SkinWidth, center.y - size.y + SkinWidth); //Going right
        _raycastBottomLeft = _transform.position + new Vector3 (center.x - size.x + SkinWidth, center.y - size.y + SkinWidth); //Going left and down-up
}

//Cast rays to the left or to the right depending on the player's movement
//Determining how far the player can go either to the left, or to the right
private void MoveHorizontally(ref Vector2 deltaMovement) 
{
        var isGoingRight = deltaMovement.x > 0;
        //The distance between the starting point and the final destination
        var rayDistance = Mathf.Abs (deltaMovement.x) + SkinWidth;
        //Where is the player going? right or left
        var rayDirection = isGoingRight ? Vector2.right : -Vector2.right;
        //Right? we start from bottom right. Left? we start fro, bottom left
        var rayOrigin = isGoingRight ? _raycastBottomRight : _raycastBottomLeft;

        //Determines how many rays we want to shoot out to the left or to the right
        for(var i = 0; i < TotalHorizontalRays; i++)
        {
            var rayVector = new Vector2(rayOrigin.x, rayOrigin.y + (i * _verticalDistanceBetweenRays));
            //Visual representation about the rays
            Debug.DrawRay(rayVector, rayDirection * rayDistance, Color.red);
            //Checks if the player hit something or not
            var rayCastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayVector, rayOrigin, rayDistance, PlatformMask);
            if(!rayCastHit) //If there was a raycast then do something, otherwise continue to loop
                continue;

            //We return true if we are on a horizotnal slope, and check if we are going right or left or hit something while going up
            if(i == 0 && HandleHorizontalSlope(ref deltaMovement, Vector2.Angle(rayCastHit.normal, Vector2.up), isGoingRight))
                break;

            //If we hit something then we can only go that far forward
            deltaMovement.x = rayCastHit.point.x - rayVector.x;
            rayDistance = Mathf.Abs(deltaMovement.x);

            if(isGoingRight)
            {
                //If we are going right, then we have to substract the skinwidth
                deltaMovement.x -= SkinWidth;
                State.IsCollidingRight = true;
            }
            else
            {   
                //The oppoiste of the if statement, if we are going left, we add the skinwidth
                deltaMovement.x += SkinWidth;
                State.IsCollidingLeft = true;
            }
            //Handles error collision, if the player hits something and go through it 
            if(rayDistance < SkinWidth + .0001f)
                break;
        }
}

private void MoveVertically(ref Vector2 deltaMovement)
{   
        //Check to see if going up or down
        var isGoingUp = deltaMovement.y > 0;
        var rayDistance = Mathf.Abs (deltaMovement.y) + SkinWidth;
        var rayDirection = isGoingUp ? Vector2.up : -Vector2.up;
        var rayOrigin = isGoingUp ? _raycastTopLeft : _raycastBottomLeft;

        rayOrigin.x += deltaMovement.x;

        var standingOnDistance = float.MaxValue;
        for(var Count = 0; Count < TotalVerticalRays; Count++)
        {
            var rayVector = new Vector2(rayOrigin.x + (Count * _horizonatalDistanceBetweenRays), rayOrigin.y);
            Debug.DrawRay(rayVector, rayDirection * rayDistance, Color.red);

            var raycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(rayVector, rayDirection, rayDistance, PlatformMask);
            //If the player hit nothing then keep going.
            if(raycastHit)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(!isGoingUp)
            {
                var verticalDistanceToHit = _transform.position.y - raycastHit.point.y;
                if(verticalDistanceToHit < standingOnDistance)
                {
                    standingOnDistance = verticalDistanceToHit;
                    //Platform we are standing on
                    StandingOn = raycastHit.collider.gameObject;
                }
            }
            //Determine the furthest distance we can move down or up without hitting anything
            deltaMovement.y = raycastHit.point.y - rayVector.y;
            rayDistance = Mathf.Abs(deltaMovement.y);

            if(isGoingUp)
            {
                deltaMovement.y -= SkinWidth;
                State.IsCollidingAbove = true;
            }
            else
            {
                deltaMovement.y += SkinWidth;
                State.IsCollidingBelow = true;
            }

            if(!isGoingUp && deltaMovement.y > .0001f)
            {
                State.IsMovingUpSlope = true;
            }

            if(rayDistance < SkinWidth + .0001f)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
}

private void HandleVerticalSlope(ref Vector2 deltaMovement)
{   
        //Give us the center of the vertical rays;
        var center = (_raycastBottomLeft.x + _raycastBottomRight.x) / 2;
        var direction = -Vector2.up;

        var slopeDistance = SlopeLimitTanget * (_raycastBottomRight.x - center);
        var slopeRayVector = new Vector2 (center, _raycastBottomLeft.y);

        Debug.DrawRay(slopeRayVector, direction * slopeDistance, Color.yellow);

        var raycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast (slopeRayVector, direction, slopeDistance, PlatformMask);
        if (!raycastHit)
                return;

        // ReSharper disable CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator

        var isMovingDownSlope = Mathf.Sign (raycastHit.normal.x) == Mathf.Sign (deltaMovement.x);
        if(!isMovingDownSlope)
            return;

        var angle = Vector2.Angle (raycastHit.normal, Vector2.up);
        if(Mathf.Abs(angle) < .0001f)
            return; //Which means there we are not on a slope, we are on something else

        State.IsMovingDownSlope = true;
        State.SlopeAngle = angle;
        deltaMovement.y = raycastHit.point.y - slopeRayVector.y;
}

private bool HandleHorizontalSlope(ref Vector2 deltaMovement, float angle, bool isGoingRight)
{
        //We do not want to move to an angle of 90
        if(Mathf.RoundToInt(angle) == 90)
            return false;

        if(angle > Parameters.SlopeLimit)
        {
            deltaMovement.x = 0;
            return true;
        }

        if(deltaMovement.y > .07f)
            return true;

        deltaMovement.x += isGoingRight ? -SkinWidth : SkinWidth;
        deltaMovement.y = Mathf.Abs (Mathf.Tan (angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) * deltaMovement.x);
        State.IsMovingUpSlope = true;
        State.IsCollidingBelow = true;
        return true;
}

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    var parameters = other.gameObject.GetComponent<ControllerPhysicsVolume2D>();

    if(parameters == null)
        return;


    _overrideParameters = parameters.Parameters;
}

public void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    var parameters = other.gameObject.GetComponent<ControllerPhysicsVolume2D>();
    if(parameters == null)
        return;

    _overrideParameters = null;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you making this in 3d world or 2d world?

Comment: One of the great things about unity is that you don't have to roll your own collision logic from scratch. This is all done in the Unity Editor with no code required. 

Just attach a box collider2d (or your preferred shape) to each game object, attach a rigidbody2d for the player and check you z index for the objects colliding. 

If you are having a problem with objects falling through, check your x y and z position for the 2 colliding game objects in the project and insure you are not using trigger collision on your ground and if you have modified any physics collision in the editor .

Comment: Also I'd make sure if you are using 2d then all your Colliders should have 2d in the name. Same goes for the RigidBody2d.
Once you have the collision working within the editor, then I'd go ahead and add the CharacterController script you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

As @Terrance said you really don't need to write your own code logic for collision detection.

Secondly I noticed `OnTriggerEnter2D` and `OnTriggerExit2D` methods in your code, that also points out to one thing that all your boxCollider2d has `isTrigger` option checked. Therefore, I suggest you to uncheck `isTrigger` option on both your player and ground as TRIGGER will never stop two objects from crossing each other (you need to have both objects have 'isTrigger' unchecked on their colliders if you don't want them to pass through each other). And use method `OnCollisionEnter2D` and `OnCollisionExit2D` to detect the collision.

**What is difference between Trigger and a Collider:**

Taking real world example Colliders are tangible object e.g you yourself and the floor you are standing on both are solid and tangible.

While trigger is intangible, example of triggers can be the walkthrough security doors; these doors are hollow from inside allowing any person to pass without any hindrance, but if you wear any metal object on yourself and pass through that "Hollow Area" between the door, the door will TRIGGER an alarm. therefore with respect to the game world you can say that the door has a trigger at it hollow area.